# How can I prevent VirtualBox from changing the permissions on the shared folder?

Tags: virtualbox, permissions

I'm using a shared folder inside VirtualBox guest. Both host and guest is Debian. VirtualBox changes folder permissions due to some security reasons, I guess. That's why all of my git folders displays a "file mode change" when I execute `git status`.

How can I prevent VirtualBox from changing the shared folder permissions and mount the shared folder as if it was mounted via SSHFS, so that I could both keep using the files without permission changes and I could create symbolic links?